# serialize complex C++ structures between client and server

Tags: c++, serialization, protocol-buffers, zeromq

I am writing C++ ZeroMQ Client and server programs for the same platform. I need to trigger some functions with arguments on the server. The arguments are  complex structures. I have just started to try this out. I am trying to fill a structure and fill it to a char* buffer to see if the bytes are filled out in sequence as per the structure.

But when i try to print the buffer, it prints garbage. Please advice what might be wrong. And is this the elegant way to do this? I cannot use gRPC or Protobuffs as the message contains complex structures.

```
    struct employee {
    uint8_t byt;
    int arr[10] = {0};
    int number;
    uint32_t acct;
};

int main ()
{
    //  Prepare our context and socket
    zmq::context_t context (1);
    zmq::socket_t socket (context, ZMQ_PAIR);
    struct employee *e = new employee;
    e->byt = 0xff;
    e->arr[0] = 15;
    e->number = 25555;
    e->acct = 45;

    std::cout << "Connecting to hello world server…" << std::endl;
    socket.connect ("tcp://localhost:5555");

    char *temp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(employee));
    memcpy(temp,e,sizeof(employee));

    zmq::message_t request(sizeof(employee));
    char *temp1 = temp;
    for (int i = 0;i<sizeof(employee);i++) {
        std::cout<<temp1[i]<<std::endl;
    }
    memcpy ((void *)request.data(),(void*)temp, sizeof(employee));
    socket.send (request);

    //  Get the reply.
    zmq::message_t reply;
    socket.recv (&reply);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Generally you should never use `malloc` in C++. If you need a raw non-owning pointer with dynamic allocation then use `new`. Or `new[]` (but then prefer either `std::array` or `std::vector` instead).

Comment: Thank you. I modified the code. But it still prints out garbage :(

    `zmq::message_t request(sizeof(employee));
    memcpy ((void *)request.data(),(void*)e, sizeof(employee));
    char * temp = (char*)request.data();
    for (int i =0; i<sizeof(employee);i++) {
        std::cout <<*temp<<std::endl;
        temp++;
    }`

Comment: Of course it prints "garbage", the data you copy into your buffer isn't in text form, so attempting to print it will print whatever characters those values represent. The operator `<<` have special overloads for `char` that prints the *character*.

Comment: So, for example, the first byte in the structure is `0xFF`, so it prints that character, which your terminal, which is likely using UTF-8 encoding, will reject as an invalid UTF-8 encoding, and print some placeholder, dummy character in its place.

Comment: So you mean to say that it is corectly serialized in the  `request.data()`. Now, how can I extract the same when I receive it ? Just cast it to `employee` type and then I could print, for example the `byt` member value ?

Comment: @Nkh, I can highly recommend you take a look at Google Protocol Buffers, which has a C++ version (as well as Python, C#, Java, etc). It's a very effective "schema first" approach to serialisation, and is easily used with ZeroMQ. Effectively one writes a schema that defines the message type (= your structure), that is compiled to C++ code by the GPB compiler, you include that C++ code in your project and that gives you a class, and that class has methods that will serialise / deserialise the class to / from byte buffers that can be ZeroMQ messages.

Comment: @bazza Thank you. I have already checked it and I really cannot use it. The problem is that I need to exchange complex structure which has deeply nested structures. This will be really error prone and time consuming to list all the structures in the proto file :(

Comment: @Nkh, Honestly, it takes no more time to to write out the structure definitions in a GPB .proto file than in C++. Given that all the other code to serialise / deserialise / print / duplicate structures is then automatically generated, error free and complete, it's a big time saver. The schema language for GPB can very easily allow for complex nested structure definitions, the 'oneof' keyword being very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Two points I would like to share here.

1. the buffer (temp) contains binary representation of your data structure. If you want to check if the content is meaningful, you can cast the pointer type back to its original pointer.ie:

struct employee * employeePtr = static_cast< struct employee *>(temp);

cout << employeePtr ->number;

...

2. The way you de-serialize is okay when the object you are trying to
   serialize occupies continuous memory. When it is not the case, you will have to handle them some other way (using stream for example). Examples of such cases include:

   - when you have pointer, shared_ptr etc. to some allocated memory
   - container classes

Comment: I will try to de-serialise on the server side and get back here with the results.

Comment: Hi! @Nkh any outcome on your tests?

Comment: Hi @stove , I was able to achieve it in a simplest way. I just created a structure for the list of arguments to be passed from client to server(luckily none of them had pointers). I just memcpy'd the structure into ZMQ buffer and sent it. On the server side I just static_cast to the structure type and I was done :). 
My understanding was wrong earlier. I was expecting it to print the individual bytes...It doesnt work that way.